# Result of Solr Search Engine

Tags: solr, solr-cell

When I write some query in query box of solr search engine and ask for result then it shows that some number of documents found (numFound), but it shows only ten documents per page. How to see further retrived documents. There is no link like "next page" or some other thing.
Please tell me how to see documents after first ten documen

Comment: Actually, why you need this? Only for debug purposes?

Comment: No, I want to see all retrived documents. But it is showing only 10 documents. I am using solr as a part of my B Tech project for document retrival

Comment: why you need to see all? actually, it's pretty heavyweight, to retrieve all docs from index.

Comment: I have big dataset at backend and My query is output of my algorithm which disambiguate polysemy words, So I want to test efficiency of my algorithm based on retrived document. Thats why I want see all retrived documents (atleast firse 25 documents)

Comment: start=0&rows=25 Why it doesn't help?

Comment: Shall I write this with query? "bank of america start=0&rows=25 ",am i right???

Comment: Thnx @Mysterion I made a mistake. Now I got it. I kept 0 and 25 in start and rows box. Thnx again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `rows` and `start` parameters to your query:

- `rows` : number of rows to be returned (default `10`)
- `start`: index of row to start from (default `0`)

So you can add those to your query like this:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/core/select?q=*:*&rows=10&start=10
```

Comment: If I am saying *bank of america*&rows=20&start=20...Then also it is giving only ten results

Comment: @Madhusudan could you post exact query. *bank of america* is invalid query

Comment: No, If I write "bank of america" in q box, Then it is giving me correct result. I don't think k anything is wrong with the query